# tar shows "is not a bzip2 file" error when uncompressing a .tar.bz file

Tags: linux, tar, extract

I've a data_or.tar.bz file

I tried to extract it with

`$ tar xjvf data_or.tar.bz`

Output is

```
bzip2: (stdin) is not a bzip2 file.
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Can only `bz2` files  be extracted with `tar` command?

-- update

```
$ file data_or.tar.bz 
data_or.tar.bz: POSIX tar archive (GNU)
```

Comment: maybe it was wrongly named? if you feel lucky try `tar xzvf ...` or `tar xvf ...` - otherwise maybe a look into the head may reveal details.

Comment: Try `file data_or.tar.bz` which should tell you if the file is simply a mis-named archive of a different type.

Comment: @Mokubai [lease see updated question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your tarball is uncompressed. The extension `.bz` is obsolete and misleading.

You can decompress using the following command:

```
tar xvf data_or.tar.bz
```

What probably happened here is that `data_or.tar.bz` was created with the `--auto-compress` switch (or `tar -cavf`) that chooses the compression algorithm from the supplied extension.

The proper extension for `bzip2` compressed files is `.bz2`, while the `.bz` extension is for `bzip` compressed files.

`bzip` uses arithmetic encoding (which is a patented algorithm), so `bzip2` was created in 1997 as a patent-free alternative. As a result, [`bzip2`](http://www.freebsdsoftware.org/archivers/bzip2.html) and [`bzip`](http://www.freebsdsoftware.org/archivers/bzip.html) are incompatible.

`tar` cannot handle `bzip` (de)compression, so the `--auto-compress` switch resulted in an uncompressed tarball.

Answer (score 1):

*tar -xvjf file.tar.bz2* >> Because the flag 'j' is used, tar command will call bzip2 to process the decompression.

Reported error explained:

**bzip2: (stdin) is not a bzip2 file.** >> bzip2 reported to parent process (tar) that the received file to process is NOT bz2 format

**tar: Child returned status 2** >> tar reports the error status received from bzip2 child process by exiting execution.
In man documentation, error status means "2 to indicate a corrupt compressed file". As bzip2 did not recognized the format, it reports it as 'corrupt'

**tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now** >> According to message received from child, compressed file is not accepted for processing

Steps to fixing the issue:

1- verify the format of the compression

```
file file.tar.bz2
```

**POSIX tar archive (GNU)** - "Or whatever other format", then correct it with the next step 2

2- `tar -xvf file.tar.bz2` - "in case its a posix tar archive format"